# Django: Some strings are automatically added to my code

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm creating a website using the django framework. But recently, I found something strange. I loaded the page at 127.0.0.1:8000, but failed. I checked the console log and found some js files with errors. Then I check the error in the js file and find some strings added to my code automatically. If I clean up the cookies and reload the page, I might load the page successfully or these strings might still appear in other js files. Why is it happen?

/error js file

```
            if ($element.data('on-label') !== undefined)
              onLabel = $element.data('on-label');

            if ($element.data('ofDate: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 09:25:20 GMT
            Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.1
            f-label') !== undefined)
              offLabel = $element.data('off-label');

            if ($element.data('icon') !== undefined)
              icon = $element.data('icon');
```

Sometime Below two strings will add into my code automatically  When I first visited the page. It looks like it's all right. There are no error log in PyCharm when i run `runserver`, only can find a console log about the wrong js file in chrome.

Date: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 09:25:20 GMT

Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.1

Comment: What error you get when you run `runserver` and what's error in js console. And what string this causes? Please elaborate more.